# SQL Oracle - Replace function in Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, where-clause

I want to use the REPLACE function in the Where clause to replace a character that I put into a input box. For example if I input `R123;R321` I want it to change my input to `R123','R321`.

Example of my query:

```
Select
    order_no

From
    order

Where
    order_no in ('&Order_No')
```

I input the data with this box:

[image: Input box]

Any help would be appreciated, or if there is some other way to do it without the REPLACE function.

Comment: You're trying to do dynamic SQL then, which isn't needed here. I'd use locate() or similar function, just concat `;` before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work like this, I'm afraid. You'll have to split input value into rows, e.g.

```
SQL> select deptno, ename
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno in (select regexp_substr('&&deptnos', '[^;]+', 1, level)
  4                   from dual
  5                   connect by level <= regexp_count('&&deptnos', ';') + 1
  6                  )
  7  order by deptno, ename;
Enter value for deptnos: 10;20

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 CLARK
        10 KING
        10 MILLER
        20 ADAMS
        20 FORD
        20 JONES
        20 SCOTT
        20 SMITH

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This works the way I want, however it doesnt seem to work for me in a bigger query

Comment: Exactly, it works the way you described. If you have another question, feel free to ask it, explaining the problem. Saying "it doesn't work" is pretty much useless.

Comment: A long while after the answer, is it possible to implement this into a search where if i dont input a value for deptno it searches all values?

Comment: Yes; that would be something like `where deptno in (what's written above) OR &&deptnos is null` - note the last part with `or`. If there are other conditions, you'll have to enclose those two conditions into brackets.

Comment: great! that works, thank you! I tried something similar but when I saw your answer I knew where i messed up